# Letsencrypt SSL certificate does not work without url prefix https://

Tags: spring-boot, ssl-certificate, lets-encrypt, certbot

My domain is: https://www.neasy.de

I ran this command:

```
git clone https://github.com/certbot/certbot
cd certbot
./certbot-auto certonly -a standalone -d neasy.de -d www.neasy.de
cd /etc/letsencrypt/live/neasy.de
openssl pkcs12 -export -in fullchain.pem -inkey privkey.pem -out keystore.p12 -name tomcat -CAfile chain.pem -caname root
```

It produced this output:

```
My web server is (include version):

The operating system my web server runs on is (include version): linux

My hosting provider, if applicable, is:

I can login to a root shell on my machine (yes or no, or I don’t know):yes

I’m using a control panel to manage my site (no, or provide the name and version of the control panel):

The version of my client is (e.g. output of certbot --version or certbot-auto --version if you’re using Certbot):certbot 0.31.0
```

4 month ago i first used letsencrypt and I was success to use it. I learned I have to generate certificate
with and without www. prefix and it is important. My company has changed the domain name from neasy.app to neasy.de and for that I deleted my old certificate and generate new one for neasy.de

Now i am in a new trouble that if i write in my browser neasy.de it does not work even if i write www.neasy.de it does not work. But for at least once time if I write https://neasy.de or https://www.neasy.de it works, and for the next time i dont need to write https:// prefix.

This issue really seems weird to me any help will be appreciated. If you already tried writting https://neasy.de then you can open firefox browser private window

Comment: which linux distro do you use?
and which webserver (apache? nginx?)

Comment: I use ubuntu and apache tomcat server, and inside my spring-boot i have a tomcat server

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using Ubuntu please follow this guide:
https://certbot.eff.org/lets-encrypt/ubuntuxenial-apache.html (jus make sure to choose your ubuntu release from the dropdown).
this will guide you through the whole process without manual work. 
Just make sure to run all apt-related commands.

Answer (score 0):

Was there a route for the old domain `neasy.app` which was redirecting the `http` traffic to `https` ? It looks like you forgot to update that route with the new domain name.
Usually when you enter any new website in the address bar of browser it by default uses http protocol. On the server site you have to do a 301 redirect from http to https.